# How many times occur pair of 1 in a vector

Tags: r

i have a problem.

I have a vector, that consists from 0 or 1 - for example (011011111011100001111). In R i need to figure out, how to count how many times appears in vector two 1, three 1, four 1 and so on. In this example vector I have 1 times 11, 1 times 111, 1 times 1111 and 1 times 11111.

Thanks a lot, Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you have an actual vector like `c(0, 1, 1, 0...)`.

Here is a solution using `table` and `rle`. I've also provided some longer sample data to make it a bit more interesting.

```
set.seed(1)
myvec <- sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE)
temp <- rle(myvec)
table(temp$lengths[temp$values == 1])
# 
#  1  2  3  4  6 
# 15  8  1  2  1
```

---

If, indeed, you are dealing with a crazy-long character string of ones and zeroes, just use `strsplit` and follow the same logic as above.

```
myvec <- "00110111100010101101101000001001001110101111110011010000011010001001"
myvec <- as.numeric(strsplit(myvec, "")[[1]])
```

Here, I've converted to numeric, but that's just so you can use the same code as earlier. You can use `rle` on a character vector too.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but i still dont know how to do it on my own .... in previous i asked for help in one vector and i thought that i will be able to do it on matrix .... but i am not .... so i ask once again .... if i have squared matrix how it would work now? ... again i need to count character 11 but in every diagonal of this matrix ....

Answer (score 2):

`rle` is your friend:

```
vec <-c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
res <-data.frame(table(rle(vec)))
res[res$values==1,]

   lengths values Freq
6        1      1    0
7        2      1    1
8        3      1    1
9        4      1    1
10       5      1    1
```